# What are BASE, LOCAL, REMOTE and cppMerged files?

Tags: git, file, mime-types

I'm working on a Visual C++ project on Win7 64bit and using git as my repository and VS2010 as my IDE. Lately I've started seeing files with the following endings:

```
.cpp.BASE.cpp
.cpp.LOCAL.cpp
.cpp.REMOTE.cpp
.cppMerged
```

Are these git merge conflict resolution files? VS2010 files? or something else?

Comment: Looks like the temp files of a merge tool. Are you using any external merge or diff tool, or have you ever run a tool like WinMerge on the file in question?

Comment: I'm using TortoiseGit - could that be the source of these files?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This seems to be an [open issue in TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=445)

Comment: This answer should just have been added as a comment to the question, since it is not answering anything. Charles Bailey's answer is the correct one. TortoiseGit is using the mergetool mechanism of git.

Answer (score 5):

`git merge` just works in the index, it doesn't create temporary files in the file system to perform its merge.

If there are conflicts during a merge and you use `git mergetool` to resolve them then `git mergetool` will write out temporary files to enable your merge tool of choice to perform a 3-way merge. Usually these are cleaned up automatically but if you interrupt the `git mergetool` workflow they can be left in place.